# $A \cup C \sim B \cup C$ with $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$ such that $A \sim B?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be sets. Suppose that $A \cup C \sim B \cup C$ and that $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$. Is it necessarily the case that $A \sim B?$ Give a proof or counterexample.
Where $\sim$ means bijection.

Actually the reciprocal is true and I already tried it, but my intuition tells me that this is not true. I would like to know if I am wrong or the counterexample is very exotic. Thanks

Comment: This is true for finite sets.  But may fail for infinite sets.  Try to make a counterexample using subsets of the integers.

Comment: The property written by the original poster is also true for infinite sets such that the cardinality of $C$ is less or equal to both the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{2\}, C = \{3, 4, \ldots\}$.

This satisfies $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$. Then $A \cup C = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and $B \cup C = \{2, 3, \ldots\}$. We have the bijection $f: A \cup C \to B \cup C$ where $f(n) = n+1$. But $A$ and $B$ have different cardinalities and clearly cannot have a bijection.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really thought with intervals and strange things but your example is great

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample is the following:

$A=\{-2,-1\}$

$B=\{-5,-4,-3\}$

$C=\mathbb{N}$

where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all positive integers.

Your property is also true for infinite sets such that the cardinality of $C$ is less or equal to both the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$.

Indeed, if the cardinality of $C$ is less or equal to both the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$, then $A\sim A\cup C\sim B\cup C\sim B$.